# Change id's with jquery and remove click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu called "LOGIN" `(id="log")` and a submenu called "Connect" `(id="connect")`. If i click on connect a form is displayed. Now, when the user login is success, i want to change the name menu "LOGIN" for the username and "Connect" for "inbox", this works, but i need to change both id's and remove
the event listener `$('#connect').click(function(e) {}` because the user was connected, and i need a new event in "inbox" like

```
$('#inbox').click(function(e) { alert("You click on inbox");    });
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


                function Login() {


                    this.loadForm = function() {

                        $("#response-container").load("formLogin.php", function() {

                            $("#formLogin").submit(function(event) {

                                var user = $("#username").val();
                                var pass = $("#password").val();

                                event.preventDefault();

                                searchData(user, pass);

                            });

                        });

                    }; //END loadForm FUNCTION




                    var searchData = function(user, pass) {

                        getdetails(user, pass)

                        .done(function(response) {

                            if (response.success) {

                                $.each(response.data.users, function(key, value) {

                                    $("#log").text(value['userName']);

                                    $("#connect").text('inbox');


                                    //HERE I WANT TO REMOVE CLICK EVENT FROM #conect and i want to
                                    //change his 'id' for a new id called 'inbox' and add a new
                                    //click event listener                                   

                                });
                            } else {

                                alert("Fail");

                            }
                        })

                        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


                        });


                    }; //END FUNCTION searchData




                    var getdetails = function(id, password) {

                            return $.getJSON("20.php", {
                                "id": id,
                                "password": password
                            });

                        } //END FUNCTION getdetails




                }; //END LOGIN CLASS



                //LISTENERS

                $('#connect').click(function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var login = new Login();

                    login.loadForm();

                });




            });
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES"><html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="21-12-16.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


  <script src="20.js"></script>


        <title>Menu</title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="header">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="log">LOGIN</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="" id="connect">Conect</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
     <div id="response-container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Changing the ID has no effect on bound events, and that is why you should avoid it. Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to bind and remove the events instead.

Comment: Why are you changing the `id`?

Comment: @adeneo Ok i need to learn more about on() and off() then. Thanks bro!

Comment: @David Thomas because i need new elements  and probably need to work with the new one id's, and can be confusing for me if i use the old id's, i dont know if i wrong, or doing a bad practice, im a noob on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#connect").unbind();` remove all events

`$("#connect").attr('id','inbox');` change id

```
$("#inbox").click(function (){

//click event

})
```

your code will now look like:

```
$.each(response.data.users, function(key, value) {

$("#log").text(value['userName']);

$("#connect").text('inbox');

$("#connect").unbind();


$("#connect").attr('id','inbox');

    $("#inbox").click(function (){

    //click event

    })

 });
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but why you are using the old id #connect if it was changed for #inbox, i change   $("#connect").click(function (){})  for
$("#inbox").click(function (){})  and works perfectly!

Comment: One more question... i dont know why when i click on the new text of the menu "Username" the text change to the old "LOGIN".

Comment: i think this is because of the page gets reloaded. have you noticed that. that is an anchor tag

Comment: You are right men, i prevent the reload, and now is permanent, 

    $('#inbox').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  })

I accept your answer, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`unbind` and `bind` are deprecated. you should use `off` for unbinding and `on` for binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbind` on jquery object to remove event and the function `attr` to change id

```
$('#connect').unbind('click').click(//function click here)
$('#connect').attr('id','inbox');
```

Refence [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: Thanks for your help bro!!